# vba: loop through user-defined data type

Tags: vba, excel

I have this elements:

```
Type Posizione
    Name As String
    Position As Byte
End Type
Public Location() as Posizioni
```

I'd like to loop between the minimum posizione().valore and the max one.

I tried with:

```
For i = LBound(Location().position) To UBound(Location().position)
```

But I receive "Invalid Qualifier" in this position.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume `Posizioni` is a typo - your type is named `Posizione`

Answer (score 2):

Your array is the variable `Location`, so you have to use this as parameter to `lbound` and `ubound`

```
For i = LBound(Location) To UBound(Location)
    Location(i).position = i
    Location(i).Name = "Hello " & i
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to find the min and max values before iterating between them. Something like this will do that:

```
Dim PosMin As Byte
Dim PosMax As Byte

PosMin = 255
PosMax = 0
For i = LBound(Location) To UBound(Location)
    If Location(i).Position > PosMax Then
        PosMax = Location(i).Position
    End If
    If Location(i).Position < PosMin Then
        PosMin = Location(i).Position
    End If
Next
For i = PosMin To PosMax
    Debug.Print i
Next i
```